# Convert a boring list of switch statements to something shorter and pleasing to look at?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a switch statement that runs like this

```
switch (abc) {
  case FILE_0:
       lf = m_a->olf[0];
       kf = m_a->pkf[0];
       break;
  case FILE_1:
       lf = m_a->olf[1];
       kf = m_a->pkf[1];
       break;
  .
  .
  default:
       LOG_ERR << "Wrong type to check";
       return 0;
}
```

This happens about 30 times and i end up with 30 cases in this single switch.
Any way to shorten it in C++ 11 ? E.g. using templates.

Comment: How exactly are `FILE_0`, `FILE_1`, etc. defined?

Comment: Don't forget the `break;` if you stay with `switch()`.

Comment: Also, your cases fall through.  Is that intentional?

Comment: look what is the last case, you can delete the whole switch ... case and just leave the last assignment

Comment: `default:` without statement is also invalid. I bet to that implicit `break;` is included in "like this".

Comment: I'm making a stab here but is `FILE_0` using element 0 (`lf = m_a->olf[0];`) and `FILE_1` using element 1 (`lf = m_a->olf[0];`) a pattern? Is the value of FILE_0 in fact 0 and FILE_1 in fact 1? If so (or you could make it so `lf=m_a->olf[abc]` is the answer. There's not enough code here to really understand what you're doing.

Comment: This question needs a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry thought just a small example would suffice. But missed the important bits. olf and pkf are vector of strings. FILE_0, FILE_1 are enums.

Comment: & yes, i do have the break and default handled properly. Pl don't worry about that. I have fixed that now in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code ain't that big to be sure about the intent, though, from what I can see in the snippet, you actually want to convert the symbolic value into an index. (Can I assume this is an enum?)

What I would do is to move that code into a separate function:

```
auto fileEnumToIndex(FileEnum file) {
    switch (file) {
       case FILE_0: return 0;
       case FILE_1: return 1;
       default: __builtin_unreachable();
    }
}
```

Your code than changes to:

```
 auto index = fileEnumToIndex(abc);
   lf = m_a->olf[index];
   kf = m_a->pkf[index];
```

If the FileEnum is a real enum, you can change the code in the function fileEnumToIndex to a simple `static_cast`

To cover the default case, you could return a `std::optional` and use the `std::nullopt` case to do some error handling. However, when FileEnum is an actual enum, I would assume error handling when you determine that value.

Comment: Thanks JVApen. yes, FILE_0, FILE_1 is a real enum. I just want to avoid repeating the cases within the switch 29 times since there is a pattern there. But i don't get what you mean in the last sentence -  "If the FileEnum is a real enum, you can change the code in the function fileEnumToIndex to a simple static_cast"

Comment: `return static_cast<int>(file);` as numeric values of the enum go from 0 to N if you don't override them

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map of `abc` and the indice and use that for determining the indice.

```
// somewhere, maybe outside functions
static const std::unordered_map<abc_type, int> table = {
    {FILE_0, 0},
    {FILE_1, 1},
    ...
};

// inside function
auto idx_itr = table.find(abc);
if (idx_itr != table.end()) {
   lf = m_a->olf[*idx_itr];
   kf = m_a->pkf[*idx_itr];
} else {
    // default case
}
```

Comment: it does something completelley different

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Yes, if the fall through is intentional.